# React Native iOS not building

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, xctest

I keep getting the following error when trying to build my react native app in Xcode. I am absolutely new to react native and had this application developed by someone else, however, they are not able to take care of the build for me. Is there anyone who ran into this issue and can provide help?

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest' for architecture armv7

I am currently using:

- react-native: 0.51.0
- Xcode: Version 9.4.1
- Target platform 8.0

I have tried turning off bitcode but this causes this:

> /Xcode/DerivedData/nativeApp-eenfjavhlxnfkfermonlqxkgbtbb/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/libRNVectorIcons.a'

Now, my question. Do I go down the road of BITCODE = OFF and try to resolve every issue that I run into or does anyone have a solution for the XCTest problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Update: I was able to solve the issue. I do not know exactly how to but I delete cocoapods and node_modules. Ran NPM install, pod install and react-native link and it was gone.

EDIT: I also checked the build config file for cocoapods and I removed -framwork XCTest.

Like I said, I have no clue what really fixed this but maybe someone finds it helpful.